# search url manager in Yii

Tags: php, yii, yii-url-manager

I implemented my project in Yii. i done URL management its working fine. but i search URL is not being proper. i added my code here. please tell me how to change this code according to my URL..

my main.php:

```
<form class="navbar-form " role="search" name="searchform" method="POST" action="<?php  echo Yii::app()->baseUrl.'/index.php/recipe/course1/';?>" id="menu-form-style" onsubmit="return ValidateSearchForm();">
 <div class="form-group">
 <input type="text" name="search" id="search" placeholder="Quick Search...." class="form-control" onkeyup="lookup(this.value);" onblur="fill();">
```

i sent to my recipe controller.

where i did like this: recipe controller

```
public function actionCourse1(){

if(isset($_POST["search"]))
$course=$_POST["search"];
$this->redirect(array('recipe/course','searched'=>$course));}

  public function actionCourse(){
    $model=new Recipe;
   if(isset($_GET['searched']))
   $count=$_GET['searched'];
      $bigArray=array(); 

  in  my configure main.php

 'searched'=>'recipe/course',
```

above config line i wants to be show.

but am getting like this

```
search/searched/asdfadfadfa
```

http://kitchenking.ebhasin.com/ 
this our website. please suggest me suitable answer

Comment: what do you want to do?

Comment: when i am enter the search button. it showing like this http://localhost/kitchenking/index.php/search/searched/asdfasdfasd

Comment: Just a tip, don't use hardcoded url's (in your form action), instead use Yii::app()->createUrl();

Comment: linking localhost? Seriously??

Comment: @davey harcoded routes is good case for 'quick fix' and check, in our case is good one. But I agree with you, before production you should change routes to createUrl() method.

Answer (score 0):

if i understod your question true try this...

```
$this->render('/recipe/course/ or your file place', array('searched'=>$course));}
```

or

```
$this->redirect('/recipe/course/searched/'.$course);
```

Answer (score 0):

Re-read http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url this one, yes I know that is not an answer, but I think your routes is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

change your config main.php:

```
'search/<searched>'=>'recipe/course',
```